# Teleport randomly an entity vertically

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to tp an entity *(an `armor_stand` named `"note"` exactly)* to a random position in axis X and Y, how can I do this ?

`/spreadplayers` only teleport random entities on axis X and Z, but it's not what I want.

I'm on 1.16 last snapshot (20w22a).

Comment: You should be able to still use `/spreadplayers` on it, but somewhere else and then copy its Z coordinate to its Y coordinate after doing some calculations on it. I'll test some things later and write an answer then.

Comment: Oh yeah that's a great idea

Comment: After tests, I can't use that, my platform where I want the armor_stands is at 70 of height in a void world, so if I put the Z coordinates value to the Y coordinates values, Z must be around 70, but my platform is not around Z 70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could randomly generate 2 numbers with a range of your choice and modify the armor stand's x and y position to that number if there is enough space at that location.  You can do random number generation with the following video

and modify the armor stand's location with mcstacker's /data generation
https://mcstacker.net/
command example

```
/data modify entity 'armor stand selector goes here' 'directory to x and y pos goes here' 'after that i cant remember the syntax after that but you can replace the nbt with scores'
```

as well you can do

```
/execute as 'armor stand selector' at @s store result entity @s 'directory to x and y pos goes here' 1 run 'scoreboard get command'
```

this doesnt work with players if you plan to use that method in the future. To make it work with players you would have to teleport the player to a armor stand or aec with random cords using this method. I hope this helped.